# iOS SWIFT and Parse getting date and time

Tags: swift, date, parse-platform, timestamp, nsdate

Using Swift and Parse, I need to get a date and time that is independent of the device settings (UTC universal date).
NSDate() works perfectly, but if the user changes timezone or time or date in device settings, than the control function becomes useless.
Basically I have to check that one user can send a maximum of 1 photo per day to Parse database.
Currently to do this I search the last 1 photo sent by CurrentUser then run control:
if objectPhoto1 dates == NSDate {blah blah bla...

The problem is that NSDate depends on the settings of the device, so if the user changes the date may send infinite photos.

Is there a way to get the current date from Parse server or Apple servers or something else?

I thought it was stupid but it is becoming a nightmare!

Perhaps I did not explain, I do not have a code to be posted because this function can not exist if I can not have a date and time correct.
Practical example:

```
// my iPhone current date and time (correct time) >> 10/12/2015 16:42:18
let TimeNow = NSDate()
print(TimeNow) // show "10/12/2015 16:42:18"
```

if i change my dates iPhone settings

```
// now my iPhone date and time are (incorrect time) >> 01/01/2002 15:30:26
let TimeNow = NSDate()
print(TimeNow) // show "01/01/2002 15:30:26"
```

Now my date and time are wrong. I need to set a variable that contains the current timestamp REGARDLESS on the settings of the device.

Comment: NSDate works fine. Where does your timezone dependency come in? In the formating or in the parsing? Please show some of your code.

Comment: NSDate uses the device date and time. If I change the date and time in my iPhone, NSDate inside the app will take that value. So I can not rely on this, but I have to use a timestamp that the user can not change in any way.

Comment: NSDate does not use any timezone. Its time value becomes localized by its input and output methods. And those, like NSDateFormater, can be set to UTC time if required. When you don't share some code then you don't get any better anser.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: A, now I understand. See how good and helpful it is to share code samples. What you need is an NTP service. See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol for details. There are free servers available but I do not know any from personal experience. I don't know if Apple runs one.

Comment: Ok, thank. How can I get the timestamp from a NTP server using Swift?

Comment: This may help. https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp However, Mo Nazemi's solution using the cloud service sounds much easier.

Answer (score 5):

Parse server time is always set to UTC. Write a simple Cloud Function to return you the current date and time which will be UTC. Something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getUTCDate", function(request, response) {

     var now = new Date();
     response.success(now);

});
```

You need to deploy your Cloud function to Parse server before using it in your iOS app. Follow the [Getting Started](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-getting-started) part of the Cloud Code guide to deploy your Cloud code on Parse.

After you deployed the cloud function on Parse server, you can call this function from iOS using Swift like this:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getUTCDate", withParameters: nil) { results, error in
      if error != nil {
          // Your error handling here
      } else {
          // Deal with your results (Date in your case) here.
     }
}
```

Comment: Now here we are! How can I implement it with swift to set a variable with the date from Parse server? Can you give me an example of cloud code + swift call? Thank you

Comment: You need to deploy your cloud code to parse and call your function from iOS as I described above.

Comment: Fantastic! I'll try it tonight!